How to change the color of the message box error message from dbeaver?
How can I change the color of the message box error message of dbeaver.
See the photo below

I tried to go to Window --> Preferences --> User Interface --> Appearance --> Colors and Font Types
but I didn’t find anything.
Can it be changed or not?
